# Получить размер картинки в байтах на php

Tags: php, изображения

Пусть на хостинге лежит загруженная картинка /upload/img.jpg
Мне нужно получить её размер в байтах, и вывести под картинкой.
Просветите, пожалуйста - как? Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filesize.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Comment: если у вас перечень картинок хранится где-то в БД, то храните там сразу и их размер. Каждый раз просить ФС отдать размер файла излишне.

Answer (score 0):

Получаем и выводим размер файла в байтах

```
$fileSize = filesize('upload/img.jpg');
echo $fileSize;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = get_headers("https://xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/1500x500-940x313.png", true);
$size = isset($data['Content-Length'])?(int) $data['Content-Length']:0;
```

Но не всегда будет работать. Для svg картинок не работает например

Comment: Осталось понять, зачем тут НТТР запрос

Comment: При упоминании хостинга, предположил что вопрошающий спрашивает про картинку на удаленном ресурсе, иначе он бы и сам думаю использовал filesize? не?